# Github Pages website compiles badly after connecting to custom domain

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a simple website with Jekyll and pushed it to a github repository.
A website was created at `<myusername>.github.io` and it looks perfect: just like it was when I hosted it locally with `jekyll serve`.

Afterwards, I connected it to a custom domain following the official instructions (changing the cname a A host), and all worked correctly: now github shows a message saying: "Your is published at ."

But now, when I enter , the website is completely "deformed": images have the wrong size, links don't work etc...

It is strange that all worked correctly when using the default domain, but now it broke.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it myself by changing the url in `_config.yml` to the new domain (It was still set to the github.io domain).